# Entity Framework doesn't update after stored procedure change

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5

I use EF 5 and VS 2012. After I change/update some stored procedure in the database and I do "Update From Database". However, it didn't update on my entity context.

What I need to do is remove the EF model and re-add again. Please help, is there any other way to solve the problem?

I am using Entity Framework for a web site project. In MSDN, what I found is for console project. I am new to Entity framework 5.

Hope there someone might helps or guide.

I couldn't post a pic. Here are my project structure after I add Entity Framework

```
+ App Code [Folder]
  - UserProfile.Context.tt
  - UserProfile.edmx
  - UserProfile.tt
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also got that issue before. What i did is just

1. Save the project
2. Open open the project
3. Update UserProfile from Database

If the above step does not work just re create your edmx model.

Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean by re creating the edmx model?